# WSO2 BPS - BPEL tutorial needed

Tags: wso2, bpel

I'm evaluating BPEL engines for an upcoming project and at the moment I have Oracle BPEL process manager and WSO2 BPS on my list.

**Requirement** : 
The need is to create a simple BPEL process (exposed as a asynchronous web service), that can invoke an external web service and wait for an asynchronous callback. I need to be able to use an XSD files which has the data types for the input and output of the web service (BPEL process).

**So far** : I have managed to download and setup your eclipse plugin and server executable to test this scenario.

**The question** : Is there a tutorial, sample or documentation as to how to do this using WSO2 BPEL eclipse plugin.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Cheers!

Buddika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the WSO2 Developer Studio from [here](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio) which has the eclipse BPEL plugin.
You can find a recent blog post by Kalpa [here](http://kalpads.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-develop-ws-bpel-for-apache-ode_18.html)
But this sample does not contain asynchronous invocations or correlations. But hope this is a good start for you.
You can find the WS-BPEL specification sample by Azeez [here](http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/ws-bpel-spec-sample-using-wso2-bps.html). It does has asynchronous invocations and correlations, but it does not have step by step guide. But if you are familiar enough with the BPEL editor, you can try this sample by your own.
You can also find this webinar [here](http://wso2.org/premium/webinars/developing-bpel-processes-using-wso2-carbon-studio), which demonstrates implementing a simple BPEL preocess.

HTH

Comment: Here you can find a simple bpel sample on handling asynchronous requests. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/graphite/products/bps/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/SampleAsynchronousProcess/